# How to prepare a dataset in Pandas for network analysis with Python NetworkX?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to build a dynamic network, using NetworkX, of B2C-companies and their suppliers. My data looks like this (in Pandas). It is indexed by the company ID:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| Company |      Supplier       |  
+---------+---------------------+
| Firm A  | {sup1, sup2, sup 3} |  
| Firm B  | {sup1, sup2}        |  
| Firm C  | {sup1, sup3}        |  
+---------+---------------------+
```

Now, if there is more than one supplier per firm, I want to create n-1 new rows just underneath the original one. My desired output would look like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| Company | Supplier |  
+---------+----------+
| Firm A  | sup1     |  
| Firm A  | sup2     |  
| Firm A  | sup3     |  
| Firm B  | sup1     |  
| Firm B  | sup2     |  
| Firm C  | sup1     |  
| Firm C  | sup3     |  
+---------+----------+
```

I also want to eliminate the curly brackets.